# React navigation shows default header with custom header only on Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a weird bug on react native app, I wrote a custom header, it appears with the default header. But it's not like 2 headers on top each other, it's just the text.

[image]

First one is my custom header like this;

```
export const HeaderWithBackTitle = ({title}: {title: string}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const HeaderOptions: NativeStackNavigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: '',
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: UIColors.darkMode,
    },
    headerLeft: () => (
      <View
        style={{alignItems: 'center'}}
        row
        backgroundColor={UIColors.darkMode}>
        <PressableOpacity marginL-12 onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <Image
            style={{width: 30, height: 30}}
            source={require('../imgs/backIcon.png')}
          />
        </PressableOpacity>
        <View style={{maxWidth: '85%'}} marginL-30>
          <Text textColor darkGreyBlue regularText>
            {title}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    ),
  };
  return HeaderOptions;
};
```

I render it like this;

```
  <Stack.Screen
        name="Entries"
        component={Entries}
        options={({route}) => HeaderWithBackTitle({title: route.params?.title})}
      />
```

No idea how it happens.

React Native version; 0.66.3
React Navigation version: ^0.6.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by doing this;

```
export const HeaderWithBackTitle = ({title}: {title: string}) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const HeaderOptions: NativeStackNavigationOptions = {
    // headerTitle: '',  <--- I was using this and it was working in older versions
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: UIColors.darkMode,
    },
    title: '', // <---- This line should be included
    headerLeft: () => (
      <View
        style={{alignItems: 'center'}}
        row
        backgroundColor={UIColors.darkMode}>
        <PressableOpacity marginL-12 onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
          <Image
            style={{width: 30, height: 30}}
            source={require('../imgs/backIcon.png')}
          />
        </PressableOpacity>
        <View style={{maxWidth: '85%'}} marginL-30>
          <Text textColor darkGreyBlue regularText>
            {title}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    ),
  };
  return HeaderOptions;
};
```

So basically I need to give empty string to the "title" property. It's really suprising that I couldn't find any question related to this, I guess many people still using old versions.

Comment: Thank you so much this was very helpful. I struggled for hours.